# nopCommerce Error: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, runtime-error, nopcommerce

I'm using MVC nopCommerce and developing custom plugin which override existing functionality of **HomepageBestSellers** (action of **ProductController** which is attributed as **[ChildActionOnly]**).

**`FilterProvider:`**

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Product.BestSellers.Filters
{
    public class BestSellersFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
    {
        private readonly IActionFilter _actionFilter;

        public BestSellersFilterProvider(IActionFilter actionFilter)
        {
            _actionFilter = actionFilter;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
        {
            if (actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(ProductController) && actionDescriptor.ActionName.Equals("HomepageBestSellers"))
            {
                return new Filter[] 
                { 
                    new Filter(_actionFilter, FilterScope.Action, null)
                };
            }

            return new Filter[] { };
        }
    }
}
```

**`Action Filter:`**

```
namespace Nop.Plugin.Product.BestSellers.Filters
{
    public class BestSellersFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;
        private readonly IStoreService _storeService;
        private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;

        public BestSellersFilter(ISettingService settingService,
            IStoreService storeService, IWorkContext workContext)
        {
            this._settingService = settingService;
            this._storeService = storeService;
            this._workContext = workContext;
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //load settings for a chosen store scope and ensure that we have 2 (or more) stores
            var storeScope = 0;
            if (_storeService.GetAllStores().Count < 2)
                storeScope = 0;

            var storeId = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.GetAttribute<int>(SystemCustomerAttributeNames.AdminAreaStoreScopeConfiguration);
            var store = _storeService.GetStoreById(storeId);
            storeScope = store != null ? store.Id : 0;

            var bestSellersSettings = _settingService.LoadSetting<BestSellersSettings>(storeScope);

            if (bestSellersSettings.IsBestSellersEnabled)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Plugins/BestSellersProducts/PublicInfo");
            }
            else
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error on **filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("Plugins/BestSellersProducts/PublicInfo");** this line:

```
Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
```

`UPDATE:`

1. Changed **BestSellersFilter.cs** according to answer.

   ```
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      var storeScope = 0;
      if (_storeService.GetAllStores().Count < 2)
          storeScope = 0;

      var storeId = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.GetAttribute<int>(SystemCustomerAttributeNames.AdminAreaStoreScopeConfiguration);
      var store = _storeService.GetStoreById(storeId);
      storeScope = store != null ? store.Id : 0;

      var featuredProductsSettings = _settingService.LoadSetting<FeaturedProductsSettings>(storeScope);

      if (featuredProductsSettings.IsFeaturedProductsEnabled)
      {
          var products = _productService.GetAllProductsDisplayedOnHomePage();

          BestSellersController objResult = new BestSellersController();
          filterContext.Result = new ContentResult { Content = objResult.PublicInfoPlugin() };
          //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
      }
      else
          base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
   ```
2. Changed **BestSellersController.cs** according to answer.

   ```
    public string PublicInfoPlugin()
    {
      var featuredProductsSettings = _settingService.LoadSetting<FeaturedProductsSettings>(_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id);
      if (featuredProductsSettings.IsFeaturedProductsEnabled)
      {
       var products = _productService.GetAllProductsDisplayedOnHomePage();
       //ACL and store mapping
       products = products.Where(p => _aclService.Authorize(p) && _storeMappingService.Authorize(p)).ToList();
       //availability dates
       products = products.Where(p => p.IsAvailable()).ToList();

       if (products.Count == 0)
           return "";

       var model = PrepareProductOverviewModels(products.Take(featuredProductsSettings.ShowFeaturedProductsNumber)).ToList();
       return RenderPartialViewToString("~/Plugins/Product.FeaturedProducts/Views/ProductFeaturedProducts/PublicInfo.cshtml", model);
      }

      return "";
   }
   ```

Now getting **null** values from all the private objects in `PublicInfoPlugin` method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a RedirectResult, set it to a ContentResult and set the Content property to the output from your plugin's action:

```
filterContext.Result = new ContentResult { Content = "Load your plugin's action here"  };
```

Comment: I have tried to give `filterContext.Result = new ContentResult { Content = "Plugins/BestSellersProducts/PublicInfo"  };` but it is returning the same string (that is "Plugins/BestSellersProducts/PublicInfo") instead loading it. I guess method is not calling and it takes string as result content. How to load the plugin action here?

Comment: You need to instantiate your plugin's controller and have the action return a string instead of ActionResult. Everything else in the action stays the same except you return    Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers.BaseController.RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, objectModel); instead of a PartialView.    If your controller inherits from BaseController, you will have it.

Comment: When I changed its type `ActionResult` to `string` with new instance of a plugin controller as you suggest, all the other objects getting null in plugin controller. My question is updated, you can see update section.

Comment: Your filter is going to have to instantiate the dependencies for the controller and pass it in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks `AndyMcKenna`, I now instantiate the controller with parametrized constructor and getting all the object values. But now the problem is I'm getting error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: controllerContext` on line `ViewEngineResult viewResult = System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);` of `Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers.BaseController.RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)`. I don't know, why it gives null context?